# Shapado rake boostrap RAILS-ENV=development error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shapado

Anyone know why I might be getting the following error when trying to get the Rails Shapado platform up and running?

```
$ rake bootstrap RAILS_ENV=development
rake aborted!
Could not open library 'libmagic.1.dylib': dlopen(libmagic.1.dylib, 5): image not found. Could not open library 'libmagic.so.1': dlopen(libmagic.so.1, 5): image not found. Could not open library 'libmagic.so.1.dylib': dlopen(libmagic.so.1.dylib, 5): image not found. Could not open library 'magic1.dll': dlopen(magic1.dll, 5): image not found. Could not open library 'libmagic1.dll.dylib': dlopen(libmagic1.dll.dylib, 5): image not found
```

I followed the README (https://github.com/ricodigo/shapado) to the T and I also believe I found an error in the 2nd step:

It should be *config/shapado.yml.sample* and *config/mongoid.yml.sample* instead of *config/shapado.sample.yml* and *config/mongoid.sample.yml*

Anything thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what OS you were on, but what you probably need to do is install that library. If you're on OSX and use Port, 'sudo port install file' should do, or else look at http://jah.pl/project/magic.html .

And yes, those files are wrong in the readme.